# Which clothing brands are most suitable for very tall men?

Tags: clothes, tall

I always have issues finding cycling clothing that fits my body shape. I am 196cm / 6ft 5in of (reasonably) slim build (but certainly not skinny). When buying a jersey that is XL they often fit me perfectly across the chest and arms but are never long enough - often leaving a drafty lower back area. I don't want to go to XXL because it will be too baggy across the chest and I'll take on the son wearing his Dad's suit kind of look.

Like most clothing (not just cycling) I find that sizes >XL are more geared towards salad-dodgers rather than those of us with long backs.

Are there any brands of clothing known for producing tops/jerseys with extra long length? What brands do other riders of similar size/body shape go for?

Comment: I'm 6'5", 190 pounds, and I wear Pearl Izumi XL jerseys as a compromise.  The length is OK, and they are maybe a bit too loose on the torso but not too bad.  I heard that Pearl Izumi was going to start offering tall sizes but I haven't found them yet.

Comment: I've started adding wiki answers to this question, add your tall brands, what they offer in tall sizes, and let the best brands get voted to the top.

Comment: I buy super cheap clothes and modify them with a sewing machine.  Not the prettiest solution but it works and costs very little compared to brand name stuff.

Answer (score 3):

## [Aero Tech Designs Cycle Wear](http://www.aerotechdesigns.com/tall-man-cycling-jersey.html)

### Tall Products

- Short sleeved jerseys
- Long sleeved Jerseys
- Bike shorts
- Bib Shorts
- Tights

### Sizes

```
Tall Cycling Jersey Size    Small   Medium  Large   XL      2XL     3XL     4XL

Fits Men's Chest inches     32-34   36-38   38-40   42-44   46-48   50-54   54-56

Garment Fabric Measures 
around Chest                38      41      44      46      48      54      56

Fabric Measurement: 
Back Length from top 
of collar down the center 
of the back to bottom       30.5    31.5    32.5    33.5    34.5    35.5    35.5

Sleeve Length from arm 
pit seam to end of cuff     21      21.5    22      22.5    23      23.5    23.5
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same boat, what you need to do is shop **Tall sizes**. I've got a 6'5" wingspan but I'm only a size medium in build. If I get something sized MT (Medium Tall) then it fits perfect. Lots of brands sell tall sizes, but it's my experience that most brands only make tall sizes for their lower-end performance gear, except for the uber expensive brands.

Search online, most shops don't stock the tall stuff so you have to order it. Visit the brands you're interested in and then search their sites for "Tall" or "Long", this usually brings up all the articles that come in tall sizes. If you fit perfect in XL width wise, then I imagine you'd fit perfect in XLTall stuff.

One brand that sells a lot of tall cycling clothing, is [aero tech designs](http://www.aerotechdesigns.com/).

Comment: Can you name at least one brand that has tall sizes ?

Comment: @Nik - I added a brand to my answer.